# Blazor CSS transition animation for wizard

Tags: c#, css, blazor, css-animations, css-transitions

I am working on a wizard (installation step by step component), which should visually display on which step I am. My main problem lies in the transition animation I want to include,when going to the next step or going back.
It works for the going back animation. Simply copying and mirroring the parts for going forward, did not work for me, but maybe I made a mistake.

This is the working transition:

[image]

I managed this with a double size background for the div which has a linear gradient and I just change the position for the transition.

To explain the process in more detail:
The background is purple on the left and gray on the right.
The default state is gray (right).
When I click "Back", the background must quickly turn purple so that I can slowly transition from purple to gray again.
I do this by setting a bool (NextPinkBool) true. This adds the CSS class "step-next-fill" which has a very fast transition so that the event "ontransitionend" is triggered and the actual transition is started by adding "step-next-animation".

The Code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i <= Steps; i++)
{
   <!-- Current Step -->
   if (i == CurrentStep)
   {
       <div class="step step-current">
           <span>Current @i</span>
       </div>
   }
   <!-- Previous Step -->
   else if (i == CurrentStep - 1)
   {
       <div class="step">
           <span>Previous @i</span>
       </div>
   }
   <!-- Next Step -->
   else if (i == CurrentStep + 1)
   {
       <div class="step step-next-background @StepNextPinkClass() @StepNextAnimateClass()" @ontransitionend="StepNextTransitionEnded">
           <span>Next @i</span>
       </div>
   }
   <!-- Other Steps -->
   else
   {
       <div class="step">
           <span>Other @i</span>
       </div>
   }
}

<div>
   <label>@CurrentStep</label>

   <button type="button" @onclick="e => GoBackwards()">Back</button>

   <button type="button" @onclick="e => GoForward()">Go</button>
</div>


@code{
   int Steps = 20;
   int CurrentStep = 0;

   bool NextPinkBool = false;
   bool NextAnimationBool = false;

   private void GoBackwards()
   {
       StateHasChanged();

       NextPinkBool = true;
       CurrentStep--;

       StateHasChanged();
   }

   private void GoForward()
   {
       CurrentStep++;
   }

   private void StepNextTransitionEnded()
   {
       NextPinkBool = false;
       NextAnimationBool = true;
   }
   private string StepNextPinkClass() => NextPinkBool ? "step-next-fill" : "";

   private string StepNextAnimateClass() => NextAnimationBool ? "step-next-animation" : "";
}
```

The CSS:

```
.step {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background-color: dimgray;
}

.step-current {
    background-color: plum;
}

.step-next-background {
    /* Left (Pink) -> Right (Gray) */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, plum 50%, dimgray 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: right top;
}


.step-next-animation {
    transition: background-position 1s ease;
    background-position: right top;
}

.step-next-fill {
    transition: background-position 0.01s ease;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

The added EventHandler for using the "ontransitionend" event:

```
namespace BlazorModalTestSteps
{
    [EventHandler("ontransitionend", typeof(EventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: false)]
    [EventHandler("onanimationend", typeof(EventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: false)]
    [EventHandler("ontransitionstart", typeof(EventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: false)]
    [EventHandler("ontransitionrun", typeof(EventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: false)]
    public static class EventHandlers
    {
    }
}
```

As I said, you'd just have to do it all the other way around for the other side, but somehow that doesn't work for me.

Unfortunately I don't really know JavaScript and wanted to try it without. But probably I will not get around to use that.

Edit: The not working part for going forward:
The div:

```
<div class="step step-previous-background @StepPreviousPinkClass() @StepPreviousAnimateClass()" @ontransitionend="StepPreviousTransitionEnded">
    <span>Previous @i</span>
</div>
```

The ethods:

```
    bool PreviousPinkBool = false;
    bool PreviousAnimationBool = false;

    private void StepPreviousTransitionEnded()
    {
        PreviousPinkBool = false;
        PreviousAnimationBool = true;
    }

    private string StepPreviousPinkClass() => PreviousPinkBool ? "step-previous-fill" : "";

    private string StepPreviousAnimateClass() => PreviousAnimationBool ? "step-previous-animation" : "";


    private void GoForward()
    {
        StateHasChanged();

        PreviousPinkBool = true;
        CurrentStep++;

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

The CSS:

```
.step-previous-background {
    /* Left (Pink) -> Right (Gray) */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, plum 50%, dimgray 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: left top;
}

.step-previous-animation {
    transition: background-position 1s ease;
    background-position: left top;
}

.step-previous-fill {
    transition: background-position 0.01s ease;
    background-position: right top;
}
```